# Problema con acentos PHP al hacer un require

Tags: php, utf-8

Tengo un problema, creo un index.php y alli pongo todo el codigo de la pagina, después para hacerlo mas dinamico creo, un header.php, un footer.php.

En cada pagina de diferentes secciónes cargo dicho header y el footer. De esta manera tengo una plantilla de cabecera y de footer para todas las secciones, pero si en esos archivos tengo un html con acentos o ñ no me los convierte al hacer el require_once.

Pero si lo incluyo en la página inicial si porque sucede esto ?.

**Codigo index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <link href="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
 <?php
   require_once(__DIR__.'/Cabeceras/Menutop.php');
 ?>
 <div class="container"><h1>Contenido de la página</h1></div>
 <!-- Footer -->
 <?php require_once(__DIR__.'/footer.php'); ?>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Contenido del footer:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1>Imatge Organització</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo hago de esta manera porque así lo tengo todo separado por módulos, así si hay algún cambio solamente tengo que tocar dicho modulo y se realiza el cambio a toda la web.

Porque en el footer no me sale el acento de Organització y en el index.php si que sale el indice de página ?

Comment: Haciendo una prueba con code snippet aquí sale sin problemas. No sé si el problema en tu contexto se deba a alguna librería que estés usando, prueba sin librerías para descartar esa posibilidad. Prueba también a poner el contenido del footer a mano, no sea que tu PHP esté emitiendo mal los acentos.

Comment: Revisa que todos tus archivos estén codificados en UTF8 sin BOM, tal vez alguno que corresponde a sección tiene otra codificación.

Comment: Yo haría lo que dice @Triby y revisaría todos los archivos que tengan la codificación correspondiente.

Comment: comparte una foto o evidencia gráfica de cómo se ve al final tu página con los acentos mal